# A matrix with labels, dashed lines

Tags: math-mode, rules, arrays

I'm trying to TeX the following matrix, from Guillemin and Pollack (1.4 #13)

[image]

The best I've been able to do is get the dashed lines with

```
\[ \left( \begin{array}{c:c} B &  C \\ \hdashline
D & E \end{array} \right) \]
```

If you want to test this try

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\begin{document}
\[ \left( \begin{array}{c:c} B &  C \\ \hdashline
D & E \end{array} \right) \] 
\end{document}
```

Output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps the following is more suitable:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{arydshln,leftidx,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
  \setlength{\dashlinegap}{2pt}
  \leftidx{_{m-r}^{\phantom{m-r}\llap{$\scriptstyle r$}}}{\left( \begin{array}{c:c}
    \smash{\overset{r}{B}} & \mathclap{\smash{\overset{n-r}{C}}} \\
    \hdashline
    D & E
  \end{array} \right)}{}
\]

\end{document}
```

The gaps between the dashes of `\hdashline` has been shortened from `4pt` down to `2pt`. [`mathtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) provides `\mathclap` (a zero-width box that is centred) and also loads [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), which provides `\overset` (a math accent-type macro). I've `\smash`ed the elements in the first row to not let the `array` delimiters over the height of `B` or `C`.

[`leftidx`](//ctan.org/pkg/leftidx) is a super-small package that adds left indexing functionality. See [Superscripts before a letter in math](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/30554/5764).

Comment: Interesting packages. First time am seeing them :-) Just put the `A=` to finish it up.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Werner -- the spacing around the parens (both inside and out) looks too wide to me.  i'd also be inclined to raise the "overscripts" a tiny bit to avoid crashing into the right-hand paren if it's tightened (ah, yes, `\smash` wouldn't work in that case).  otherwise, very nice.

Answer (score 2):

The package `nicematrix` provides tools to add exterior rows and columns to a matrix. It has built-in commands to draw dotted lines (with real rounded dots).

For other styles of rules, it's possible to define letters (in the preamble of the array) and commands (for the horizontal rules) for any
Tikz style of line.

You need at least version 6.6 of `nicematrix` (2022-02-16).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{code-for-first-row = \scriptstyle,code-for-first-col = \scriptstyle }

$A = \begin{pNiceArray}{c:c}[first-row, first-col, columns-width=auto]
    & r & n-r \\
r   & B & C \\
\hdottedline
m-r & D & E 
\end{pNiceArray}$

\bigskip

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    custom-line = 
     {
       letter = I , 
       command = hdashedline , 
       tikz = dashed ,
       width = \pgflinewidth
     }
  }

$A = \begin{pNiceArray}{cIc}[first-row, first-col, columns-width=auto]
    & r & n-r \\
r   & B & C \\
\hdashedline
m-r & D & E 
\end{pNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]