# is it possible to add dashed lines between rows/column of pmatrix from amsmath?

Tags: amsmath, matrices

I wish these packages from amsmath have more options!

Is there a way to add a macro to add dashed lines between rows and columns for a matrix typeset using `pmatrix`? Similar to what is being asked here [A Matrix with labels, dashed lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79134/a-matrix-with-labels-dashed-lines)

But I can't use the solution given in the above, since I have to use `pmatrix`

I have to use `pmatrix`, since this is what `Scientific Word` supports/produces when I click on add a matrix from the GUI and I have no control over changing this.  Here is a typical Latex file generated using one matrix

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\begin{document}
This is my matrix

$
\begin{pmatrix}
\sin x & \cos x\\
B & A
\end{pmatrix}
$
\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I can't modify the code generated and change `pmatrix` to say `array` or such in order to use the solution shown above, since then SW will not display the result on the screen when I open the file again to continue working on it. But what I can do is add a macro in the  preamble to modify the definition of `pmatrix` since I use `texlive` 2013 to build the file and only use `SW` for entering the math since it is much easier for me to do so at this time.

So, I'd like to ask for help if there is a way to use some `\renewcommad` or such to replace `pmatrix` with `array` or some other solution in order to add these dashed lines between rows and columns when compiling the file?

thank you,

Comment: I'm sure also SWP allows for inserting raw LaTeX code.

Comment: @egreg Yes, ofcourse it does. But then why would I use the GUI in the first place? :) I am trying to typeset very complicated matrix with lots of math (aerodynamics have so many subscripts and superscripts) and it is much easier to do it using SWP at this time. I could not do it using raw Latex. Not good yet. I'll be late finishing the HW if I write all this using raw Latex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a one-off basis, you can replace the `pmatrix` environment by a `BMAT` (from the [easybmat](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/easybmat) package). However, `BMAT` requires more details about the columns, so this won't work if you have multiple matrices with different sizes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{easybmat}
\renewenvironment{pmatrix}{\left(\begin{BMAT}(b){l.cr}{t.cb}}
{\end{BMAT}\right)}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
1_{j} & 1 & 1 \\
1_{j} & 1 & \frac{111}{222} \\
1 & 1_{j} & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

You could also do this on a case-by-case basis, by putting the redefinition in a group.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{easybmat}

\begin{document}
\[
\bgroup
\renewenvironment{pmatrix}{\left(\begin{BMAT}(b){l.cr}{t.cb}}
{\end{BMAT}\right)}
\begin{pmatrix}
1_{j} & 1 & 1 \\
1_{j} & 1 & \frac{111}{222} \\
1 & 1_{j} & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\egroup
\]
\end{document}
```

Ultimately, if a GUI means you have to resort to hacks like this, it is probably more trouble than it is worth.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{arydshln}  
\begin{document}
This is my matrix

$\left(\,
\begin{array}{ : c : c : }\hdashline
\sin x & \cos x\\\hdashline
     B & A       \\\hdashline
\end{array}\,\right)
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Unfortunately I can't use it with SWP now as I said, I can't change the code after `\begin{document}` as SWP does not understand `array` so the above will not display on the GUI. But please keep this answer, it is useful and I can use it when I graduate to using raw Latex one day.